# Why my code was unable to terminate after first request when I removed next() from this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const express =require ('express')
let app= express()

function logger (req,res,next) {
   console.log(new Date(), req.method, req.url)
   next()
  }
   app.use(logger)
   app.get('/',(req,res) => {
   res.json({name:'Some name'});
 }
 )


app.listen(3000,()=>console.log('Server Started'))
```

Here the request is not getting terminated after removing next() from the function logger(), when I tested it using postman. What is the reason behind the same? What actually this next() is doing here in this context of code?

Comment: `next()` runs the next middleware ?!

Comment: `next ` runs the next middlewares (if present, in your case no) and then the route you defined. When you comment `next` it doesn't come into your route

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I tried the same, still, I had to write next() in order to terminate the request.

Comment: @JibyJose can you please elaborate your point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the line `app.use(logger)` you use a middleware in your app. This means that all requests go through that first. In order for the execution to continue you have to call the next() method inside it.
[Using middleware.](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. For your explanation.